# Adding std::string values to CListBox ends up as gibberish

Tags: mfc, c++-cli, stdstring, clistbox

OK, what is wrong with this?

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vectorList;

    try
    {
        CMSAToolsLibraryWrapper wrapper;

        __int64 lResult = wrapper.SetDatabasePath(std::string("d:\\Test.xml"));
        __int64 iNumPublishersRead = 0;
        if (wrapper.ReadPublisherData(iNumPublishersRead))
        {
            vectorList = wrapper.GetPersonnelNames(true);
            for (std::string& strName : vectorList)
            {
                m_lbNames.AddString((LPCTSTR)strName.c_str());
            }
        }
    }
    catch(_com_error *e)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Problem"));
    }

    //CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```

If I place a breakpoint on the `AddString` call the  `strName` value is correct. But my `CListBox` ends up with Chinese characters. Why ?

Comment: Think about what happens when the `OnBnClickedOk` function returns, and the `vectorList` variable goes out of scope and is destructed together with all contained strings. Where do the pointers then point?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But I am populating a CListBox with values. Doesn't it copy those? I have not had to worry about that before. For example, I could have done `AddString(_T("Fred"))`;

Comment: String literals never go out of scope, their lifetime is the same as the full program, which is why you can use pointers to them anywhere. As for the problem with the listbox, I don't *think* it copies the actual string, but I'm not sure, and I can't seem to find anything saying if it does or not. If you make the vector a member variable of your class, or otherwise make sure it will not be destructed, does it work then?

Comment: @Ðаn Huh? Where is that is my answer code? And the C++/CLI code is in the `CMSAToolsLibraryWrapper ` wrapper. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending `char` strings to a function that requires `wchar_t` strings. The `(LPCTSTR)` cast is masking the error message that would have told you what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vectorList;

    try
    {
        CMSAToolsLibraryWrapper wrapper;

        __int64 lResult = wrapper.SetDatabasePath(std::string("d:\\Test.xml"));
        __int64 iNumPublishersRead = 0;

        if (wrapper.ReadPublisherData(iNumPublishersRead))
        {
            vectorList = wrapper.GetPersonnelNames(true);
            for (std::string& strName : vectorList)
            {
                CString strName2(strName.c_str());
                m_lbNames.AddString(strName2);
            }

            UpdateData(FALSE);
        }
    }
    catch(_com_error *e)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Problem"));
    }
}
```

Putting the `std::string` into a `CString` first and then passing **that** with `AddString` works.

Comment: This solution has nothing to do with the original problem or your `CEdit` control. It has to do with you using `CString` instead, which is passed *by value* and copied correctly. You are no longer passing pointers to data that will be destructed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It does relate. Forget the CEdit code. That is a side. My original was direct from std::string to listbox. And now I used CSreing. And your comment explains why that works. Thanks.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My original problem was not a `CEdit` control. It was using `AddString` on a `CListBox`. Thanks.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the control makes a *copy* of the string either way, so destruction of the string after the call doesn't matter. The real reason this works is that `CString` internally holds `wchar_t` characters but will accept a `char*` string and do a conversion when you assign it.